# Referencing a sheet in another workbook based on the 'master' sheet's name

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

**Edit:** Solved; I reloaded Excel, ran a Find/replace, and it just *worked*.

<strike>I'm pulling productivity data from multiple workbooks into one 'master', each source book is set up the same with separate sheets for January, February, etc.</strike>

Is it possible in the master to refer to source sheets without having to specify "month", but instead just pull from the sheet with the same name? I.E. the January sheet in the Master book will autonatically pull from January in all the source books, but copying the formula to the February sheet will automatically pull data from the February sheets in the sources.

A normal find/replace for each month wouldn't work as some of the source books are password protected, and this seems to require the password for each book for every instance - around 450 cells.

e: the existing formulas are of the form `=[Anna.xlsx]January!B16+[Ben.xlsx]January!B16` etc, if I can replace "January" with "sheetName" then I'm a happy bunny

Thanks

Comment: I think you should write VBA macro operated on this sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the current sheet using this formula;

```
    =REPLACE(CELL("filename"),1,FIND("]",CELL("filename")),"")
```

You can then build your lookup formula using an 'INDIRECT' formula

for example,

```
    =INDIRECT(YourSheetName&"!A1")
```

In this example, I've just populated 1 cell with the sheet name value, and given it a name of YourSheetName. You could of course put this whole formula in there, but wouldn't be very efficient if you're using it many times in a sheet

```
    =INDIRECT(REPLACE(CELL("filename"),1,FIND("]",CELL("filename")),"")&"!A1")
```

Comment: Thanks. This constantly references the active sheet though; so whenever another sheet is looked at, the workbook will try to update all pages. Also, I have 450 cells per sheet referencing up to 16 other workbooks - changing these all at this point would be tedious to say the least!